# Is GAP NP-hard with at most two balls per bins?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

The generalized assignment problem (GAP) [1] is given by:

- **Instance:** A pair $(B,S)$ where $B$ is a set of $m$ bins (knapsacks) and $S$ is a set of $n$ items. Each bin $j∈B$ has a capacity $c(j)$, and for each item $i$ and bin $j$, we are given a size $s(i, j)$ and a profit $p(i, j)$.
- **Objective:** Find a subset $U ⊆ S$ that has a feasible packing in $B$ and maximizes the profit of the packing.

In [1], the authors proved that GAP is NP-hard even when:

- $p(i,j) = 1$ for all items $i$ and bins $j$.
- $s(i,j)=1$ or $s(i,j)=1+δ$ for all items $i$ and bins $j$.
- $c(j)=3$ for all bins $j$.

Analyzing this instance, I can see that GAP is NP-hard when $p(i,j)=1$ for all items $i$ and bins $j$ and each bin can pack at most ***three*** balls. This observation raises the following question for me.

**My question:** Is GAP NP-hard when $p(i,j) = 1$ for all items $i$ and bins $j$ and each bin can pack at most ***two*** balls?

---

[1] [A Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme for the Multiple Knapsack Problem](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1255&context=cis_papers)

Comment: How much is $\delta$?

Comment: I think the authors wanted to say that the sizes are either $1$ or larger than $1$. I think it does not matter much about $\delta$, but probably $0<\delta<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce [numerical 3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_3-dimensional_matching) (N3DM) to your problem.

Given an instance of N3DM $X\times Y\times Z$ with the bound $b$, say $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\},Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\},Z=\{z_1,\ldots,z_k\}$, you can construct $k$ bins with capacities $b-x_1+M+M^2,\ldots,b-x_k+M+M^2$, and $2k$ balls with sizes $y_1+M,\ldots,y_k+M, z_1+M^2,\ldots,z_k+M^2$, where $M$ is a very large number. Now there is a valid solution to the N3DM instance if and only if you can pack all the $2k$ balls.

Comment: Thanks. From N3DM to my problem that's fine. On the other hand, if we pack all $2k$ balls, how do we know that we solved N3DM? I mean maybe a bin packs more than two balls?

Comment: @Jika Didn't you say "each bin can pack at most two balls"?

Comment: @Jika Maybe I misunderstood your question, but it doesn't matter, this construction still works. If a bin packs more than two balls, it must pack more than two $y_i$ balls and zero $z_i$ balls, then another bin would pack more than one $z_i$ balls, which is impossible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Each bin packs at most two balls, so my comment did not have much sense. So, if I pack $2k$ balls in my problem then each bin packs 2 balls and they must be one $y_i$ ball and one $z_i$ ball?

Comment: Yes, two $z_i$ balls are overweight and zero $z_i$ balls would make another bin overweight.

Comment: From my second question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116859/partition-a-multiset-into-pairs-that-sum-up-to-given-numbers?noredirect=1#comment247198_116859 I understand now that GAP is NP-hard even if the profits are all 1, i.e., $p(i,j)=1$ for all items  and bins , and the sizes of the items do not depend on the bins, i.e., $s(i,j)=s_i$ for all items .